# How to hover on donut chart arcs using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium

Have a donut chart as below

[image]

and when i hover over the arc which is in color then it will display as below

[image]

and the html code for this is as below[image]

I used mousehover of actions class but no use. Can some one please help

Comment: Code trials and relevant HTML in text format please.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why action class is not working. Did you try moveToElement from actions class

```
  WebElement donut =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//svg//circle[@class='AdvisoriesPopoverWidget donut']"));
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.moveToElement(donut).perform();
```

Comment: Yes Need to hover on colored arc only

Answer (score 0):

You can try pixel navigation. Select a specific element and specify the distance in pixels along The x and Y axis

```
new Actions(getBrowser().getDriver()).moveToElement(yourWebElement, xOffset, yOffset).build().perform()
```